# How to avoid validation triggers being fired upon postback

Tags: c++, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Have an aspx page. When a user clicks (+) to add a phone number, its supposed to check and see if there is a previous number entered. If there is, only then should another textbox dynamically be added to add another phone number etc. However, its not firing the validation trigger on the press of (+) because it is allowing the page to do a postback although nothing is entered, as well as when the page does the postback it fires the validation triggers i have on other controls and the respective error messages show. how to avoid this?

ASPX

```
    <tr><td class="labels">Tel. No. (XXX-XXXX) </td>
    <td class="tb">
    <asp:TextBox ID="PN1" runat="server" width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonAdd1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/add.jpg" 
     Height="16px" Width="23px"  AlternateText="Add another Phone Number" 
     CausesValidation="False"  Onclick="TelNum2_Click" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorPN" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Please enter a VALID Phone Number in the format XXX-XXXX" ControlToValidate="PN1" Display="Dynamic" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Font-Bold="True" ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></tr>




  <tr id="phoneNum2" runat="server"><td class="labels"> Tel. No 2. (XXX-XXXX)</td>
  <td class="tb"><asp:TextBox ID="PN2" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonAdd2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/add.jpg" 
   Height="16px" Width="23px" AlternateText="Add another Phone Number" CausesValidation="False" 
   Onclick="TelNum3" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorPN2" runat="server"
   ErrorMessage="Please enter a VALID Phone Number in the format XXX-XXXX" 
   ControlToValidate="PN2" Display="Dynamic" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Font-
   Bold="True" ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></td></tr>

   <tr id="phoneNum3" runat="server"><td class="labels"> Tel. No 3. (XXX-XXXX)</td>
   <td class="tb"><asp:TextBox ID="PN3" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorPN3" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a VALID Phone Number in the format XXX-XXXX" 
    ControlToValidate="PN3" Display="Dynamic" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Font-
    Bold="True" ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></td></tr>
```

CS

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Visible = true;
        BtnNew.Visible = true;
        BtnDelete.Visible = false;    
        BtnUpdate.Visible = false;
        BtnSave.Visible = false; 
        BtnCancel.Visible = false;
        pubvar.DisableAllControls(Page);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            processAgentData.Visible = false; //area in which textboxes are displayed
            phoneNum2.Visible = false;
            phoneNum3.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            processAgentData.Visible = true;
        }


    }


   protected void TelNum2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PN1.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                phoneNum2.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                phoneNum2.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
    }
    protected void TelNum3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PN2.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                phoneNum3.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                phoneNum3.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `CauseValidation = true` on your image button.

Comment: Ah! I missed that. Although I have updated my answer. Your control should initiate validation for the page to be validated.